# One muscle a day workout for skinny guys

Tags: workout-routines

I am 6'2 and weigh 67 kg.I am currently working out a muscle per day ,for six days.I do five exercises for each muscle . Is this ideal for gaining muscle mass?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a duplicate of that.

Comment: The most important part of gaining muscle is your diet.  In fact, more than half of fitness is focused on diets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your description of yourself, height, bodyweight, and the fact you are a beginner, *you should be using a beginner routine*.  The truth of the matter is that the one muscle group per workout is an advanced body builder split.  There really needs to be a foundation of muscle for that to work.

**Training for Beginners**

Jim Stoppani has a good approach to building mass taking you [from beginner to advanced](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/beginner-to-advanced-bodybuilder-in-12-weeks.html) in 12 weeks.  It boasts some features that you should pay attention to:

- Each phase will have you lifting heavier, and adding volume.  This is progressive overload.
- You only need to introduce more variety as your work capacity increases to keep improving.
- You start with major compound movements like squat, bench press, rows, etc. and get more specialized over time.

The breakdown is like this:

- Phase 1: full body training every session 3x per week (week 1-3)
- Phase 2: 2 day split training 4x per week (week 4-6)
- Phase 3: 3 day split training 3x per week (week 7-9)
- Phase 4: 4 day split training 4x per week (week 9-12)

Now, Jim Stoppani's program isn't the only way to gain mass, but it addresses the needs of a beginner body builder and adapts as they grow.  The truth is you won't be able to keep up with Phase 1 while you are using the weights you use in Phase 4.  This is due to recovery needs.  Your body needs to be able to rebuild itself into a stronger and bigger you after the stress of training.

**The other side of the coin is food**

The point of bodybuilding is to get bigger muscles, but stay lean enough that you can see them.  You need to eat like a bodybuilder to see the improvements you want.  It requires calories to build muscle, but you don't want to just blindly eat everything in sight.  Another bodybuilding article on a [mass building diet](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/mass_gain_diet_tips.htm) outlines what your diet should consist of:

- 15-17 Calories per pound total body weight
- 1g protein per lb total body weight
- Split food into 4-7 meals a day--it really depends on what you are comfortable with
- Get your Calories from real food

You'll find that supplements on a mass gaining diet may not really be necessary, other than multivitamins and omega-3s.  You will do better eating your carbs from rice and potatoes than you will from a tub of mass gainer.

If you have a hard time gaining mass, Jordan Syatt had [a good article](http://www.jcdfitness.com/2014/01/attention-skinny-guys-learn-how-you-can-build-more-muscle-than-ever-using-this-fool-proof-system/) covering the typical issues "hard gainers" have:

- Hardgainers usually under eat.  Track calories to see how much you are really eating.
- They may be following fad diets or misunderstanding dietary advice.
- Not training properly.  3-4x a week is the sweet spot for mass gaining.
- Not sleeping properly.  Most muscle building happens while you are asleep.  Sleep is precious.
- Lack consistency in any of these areas.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have muscles in first place,let alone working them separately,looking at your height and weight it seems that you are underweight.

I'll suggest you that you should eat big and perform compound lifts like **Squats**, **Dead-lift**, **Bench Press**, **Overhead press** etc. and you'll gain in size.No exercise is going to work for you if you are not eating enough. Don't worry about gaining some fat in the process,once you gain some muscle mass its easy to cut fat later,its very hard to gain muscle without fat.

Grab some beginner program like **Starting Strength** or **Stronglifts 5X5** and follow it blindly without modification,It'll do wonders for you.

just Remember to **Eat Big And Lift Heavy**

Comment: +1 I would upvote this twice if I could. This answer addresses the 2 most important points for skinny guys (I know because I am (still) one, but have achieved some mass gain):  compound lifts + massive calorie intake